# How to avoid repeating myself in Salt states?

Tags: configuration-management, salt-stack

We have two different environments, dev and production, managed by a single Salt server.
Something like this:

```
base:
  'dev-*':
    - users-dev
  'prod-*':
    - users-prod
```

`user-dev` and `users-prod` states are pretty much the same, like this:

```
{% for user, data in pillar['users-dev'].items() %}
{{ user }}-user:
  user.present:
    < ...something... >
{{ user }}_ssh_auth:
  ssh_auth.present:
    < ...something... >
{% endfor %}
```

We did not want to duplicate the code so our initial idea was to do something like this:

```
{% users = pillar['users'].items() %}
include:
  - users-common
```

and then to refer to `users` in `users-common`, but this did not work because the proper Jinja syntax was `set users = pillar['users'].items()` and this was not intended to work across Salt states includes.

So, the question is how to do it properly?

Answer (score 2):

All jinja is evaluated before any of the states (including the `include` statements) are evaluated.

However, I would think you would just be able to refer directly to `pillar['users'].items()` inside of `users-common`.  Is it not allowing you to access pillar from within that state?